# tailwindcss not using my custom class inside breakpoints

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to add some animation on the height property inside the md breakpoint but tailwind won't use my class

```
 <div className={`h-12 bg-blue flex w-full text-white fixed mt-1 md:bg-white ${scrolling ? 'md:animationNav md:h-16' : 'md:animationBasisNav md:h-20'} lg:bg-gray-500 `}>
<p>test</p>
</div>
```

my sass

```
.animationNav{
    -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out;

    img{
        -webkit-transition: padding 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: padding 1s ease-in-out;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
.animationBasisNav{
    -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
    img{
        -webkit-transition: padding 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: padding 1s ease-in-out;
        padding: 0.25rem
    }
}
```

I tried adding it to the tailwindcss utilites like this, but still won't work

```
@layer utilities {
    .animationNav{
        -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
    
        img{
            -webkit-transition: padding 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: padding 1s ease-in-out;
            padding: 0;
        }
    }
    .animationBasisNav{
        -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
        img{
            -webkit-transition: padding 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: padding 1s ease-in-out;
            padding: 0.25rem
        }
    }

}
```

this when loadig the page

[image]
[image]

When scrolling the height inside the md work but my classname does not

[image]
[image]

any idea why tailwindcss won't use my class? do I need to config something in the tailwind.config.js

Answer (score 7):

If you want to add responsive variants to your custom classes, you should use [`@responsive`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#responsive):

```css
@responsive {
  .animationNav { ... }
}

/* Output */

.animationNav { ... }

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .sm\:animationNav { ... }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .md\:animationNav { ... }
}

/* etc. */
```

Some notes the doc:

> This is a shortcut for writing out @variants responsive { ... } which works as well.

> The responsive variants will be added to Tailwind's existing media queries at the end of your stylesheet. This makes sure that classes with a responsive prefix always defeat non-responsive classes that are targeting the same CSS property.

Comment: is it no better inside @variant reponsive because it will be all the same behavior on all breakpoints and I do not want to individually change them

Comment: yes, it'll be the same on all breakpoints, but guess what... you're not supposed to use all of them at once. What you'll do is something like this: `md:animationNav` --> only apply this class at md resolution

Comment: Great works very well! Thank you!

Comment: For me it was just a case of using `\:` to escape the colon e.g. `@screen md { .md\:example {color:#fff; } }`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to add a new utility. . One way would be to write your new utilities in your CSS with the notation @layer.

```
@layer 
 utilities {
  .animationNav {
   -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
  }

//and so on:
```

Here is the link to the doc:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities

Comment: when adding my animation to my sass file inside the @layer utilities, it still does not work

Comment: @MaximeGhéraille You compile your sass and your finished css then has your new utility? have you looked. if you do not work with fingerprint empty the browser cache.

Answer (score -1):

as easy as

```
@screen md {
  // whatever
}
```