# Custom classes added responsive variants didn't work

Tags: tailwind-css

I try to do as what [tailwindcss not using my custom class inside breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65899657/tailwindcss-not-using-my-custom-class-inside-breakpoints) said, but it's still didn't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="img-box-md overflow-hidden rounded-sm lg:img-box-lg">
    ...
  </div>
<template>
......
<style lang="postcss" scoped>
@responsive {
  .img-box-lg {
    height: 9.2vw;
  }
}
</style>
```

I tried to use `@responsive` to make the class to be responsive, but failed to find it works in console in large width

Comment: try to replace `@responsive`  with  `@variants responsive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know where the problem is: I use windicss as my alternative to Tailwind, but there is some strange differences between their grammar. For example, the correct grammar of the windicss is

```
@variants lg {
   .lg\:img-box-lg {
     height: 9.2vw;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code you provided is correct.

Demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/HIvIPglMqf

Comment under question about using `@variants responsive` instead of `@responsive` can be misleading - they are the same (second one is just shorter alias).

Docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#responsive

Restart compilator and check again. My guess is that you are using new JIT mode where problems in recompiling config is common issue.

Comment: I know where the problem is: I use windicss as my alternative to Tailwind, but there is some strange differences between their grammar.
For example, the correct grammar of the windicss is
`@variants lg {
  .lg\:img-box-lg {
    height: 9.2vw;
  }
}
`