# Tailwind responsive breakpoints don't override padding

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Here's my div:
`<div class="h-full w-screen p-24 text-white text-shdw-light flex flex-col gap-10 lg:px-46"></div>`
Why doesn't it decrease the padding? `lg:px-46`(px-46 is a custom class) should mean that horizontal padding is 46 for resolutions above `lg` and when it goes below that, use `p-24` right? If I replace `lg:px-46` with `lg:hidden` it works as expected. Do breakpoints simply not work with padding?

Comment: You have a typo: `px-46` is not a valid tailwind CSS class: you probably want to use `px-44` or `px-48`. See [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding).

Comment: @Terry I forgot to mention, px-46 is a custom class which adds `11.7rem`s of padding. I know this is a very dirty way to align something and I'll be doing it properly but nonetheless it should still work shouldn't it?

Comment: It should, therefore I’m not sure why it doesn’t work in your case. Can you create a [mcve]? Stacksnippets probably can’t afford the complexity but you can try creating a test case on codesandbox.io and share the link here.

Comment: You can: you just need to use `@responsive`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65899657/tailwindcss-not-using-my-custom-class-inside-breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I think responsive breakpoints don't really work with custom classes like I had. Removing the custom class and adding padding onto `body` instead of the container itself to align everything made breakpoints work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be more useful to others if you would provide an example.